# Error writing headers. Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to read some data from https server using HttpWebRequest and this code works OK for HTTP but thrown exception with HTTPS: (Android Proyect)

> Message: "Error writing headers"
>
> Response: (null)
>
> Source: "System"
>
> Status: System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.SendFailure
>     TargetSite: {System.Net.WebResponse EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)
>
> {System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException:  The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed. at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult)}
>
> InnerException: {System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Found some information but the proposed solutions do not work.

Can anybody help me.

This is my code:

```
string serviceUrl = "https://erp.xxxxxxx.com/xmlrpc/";
XmlRpc.serviceUrl = bbdd.connection.url + "common";

var parameterArray = new object[3];
parameterArray.SetValue(bbdd.connection.bbdd, 0);
parameterArray.SetValue(user.Text, 1);
parameterArray.SetValue(pass.Text, 2);

XmlRpc.call("login", parameterArray);

-----------------------------------------------------------

public static object call(string methodName, params object[] args)      {   

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);

request.UserAgent = "XML-RPC Client (Xamarin)";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Timeout = 6000;

Stream stream = (Stream)request.GetRequestStream();
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))     {
writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("methodCall");
            writer.WriteElementString("methodName", methodName);

            writer.WriteStartElement("params");
            if (args != null)
                foreach (object arg in args)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("param");
                    SerializeParam(writer, arg);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }


XmlTextReader xmlResponse = new XmlTextReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()); <- here throw exception
```

[....]
}

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X.iOS Cycle7 seems to break SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931588/x-ios-cycle7-seems-to-break-ssl)

Comment: i have this problem in one Android proyect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By another person having the same problem:

Maybe my solution is not the best , but it works with https.

INFO -> Connect with the service xml-rpc odoo from xamarin (c#)

```
Process proceso = null;
try {
    var info_proceso  = new ProcessStartInfo    {
    FileName = "curl",     
    Arguments = string.Format("-k {0} --data \"{1}\"", 
          bbdd.connection.url + "common",
          "<methodCall><methodName>login</methodName>" +
          "<param><value>your_bbdd</value></param>" + 
          "<param><value>your_user_or_mail</value></param>" + 
          "<param><value>your_pass</value></param></methodCall>"),
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = false,
    };

    proceso = Process.Start(info_proceso);
    var res = proceso.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally {
        if (proceso != null && proceso.HasExited == false)
        proceso.Kill();
    }
```

*[thanks , you made me much stronger]*

Answer (score 1):

Mono decodes only TLS 1.0

Switch to Xamarin beta channel and in your project settings, ios Build, set "Use NSURLSession" instead of "Mono HttpClient".

See [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error on OS X 10.8. Certificates, provided by the OS, were outdated in this case. On which platform are you deploying?

Comment: Windows with Xamarin development studio . It is an Android application and the server is linux.

I just read that if I install the certificate looks like it could solve the problem.

I'll try.

You gotta fix the problem ?, I 've seen enough people with that particular error.   

Thank you very much.

Comment: We stopped to support the OS. There was no solution we came up with, but to be honest didn't put too much effort in it, as OS X 10.8 is relatively old nowadays anyway. Hope you have luck with the certificates.